# Grep csv with arguments from another csv

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, grep

If I have the following in file1.csv (space delimited):

```
RED 4 VWX
BLUE 2 MNO
BLUE 7 DEF
PURPLE 6 JKL
BLACK 8 VWX
BROWN 1 MNO
RED 1 GHI
RED 7 ABC
```

And the following in file2.csv (comma delimited):

```
BROWN,2
RED,5
YELLOW,8
```

Is there a way to use file2.csv to search file1.csv for matching lines? Currently, if I want to use line 1 terms from file2.csv to search file1.csv, I have to manually enter the following:

```
grep "BROWN" file1.csv | grep "2"
```

I would like to automate this search to find lines in `file1.csv` that match BOTH items in a given line in `file2.csv`. I have tried some awk commands, but am having a hard time using awk output as an argument in grep. I am running all this through a standard Mac terminal (so I guess I'm using bash?) Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to use the `awk` output as an argument to `grep`. Use `awk` to do the matching as well.

Answer (score 1):

**awk** one-liner

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) && a[$1]==$2' FS=, file2.csv FS=" " file1.csv
```

`FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}` : To read first input file, here `file2.csv` and create an associative array `a` with keys as column 1 in `file2.csv` and value as `item number`.

`($1 in a) && a[$1]==$2`: While iterating over second input file i.e `file1.csv` here check if column 1 value exists as key in array `a`. If it exists check if `item number` matches. If it matches the result will be `1` and line would be printed.

Or

simply using **grep**

```
grep -wf <(tr "," " " <file2) file1
```

Here we are replacing `,` with space  in file2 using `tr` and using each line in file2 as pattern to search in `file1` using the `-f` option provided by our lovely `grep`

`-w` is to match with word boundaries so that `ABC 1` won't match with `ABC 123`

Comment: Can you really change `FS` like that? Neat!

Comment: The grep method will give false matches if file2.csv contains `A 1` and file1.csv contains `A 12`

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for first comment. For second I've updated grep solution using `-w` option.

Comment: For some reason, when trying each of the one-liners, I don't get any output. Shouldn't the results print below?

Comment: @DanielEsporma: haha yes result should come below this command. That was cute :P Are you sure you're giving the files in correct order. The one with the comma separated will come first and then the other as file1.csv. Also the input you've provided has no matching records.

Comment: @batMan: For some reason, I can't seem to get it to output anything. I've even tried switching the two around. Would you mind explaining how the first one-liner works?

Comment: @DanielEsporma: first let's do basic sanity at your end. Paste this line `YELLOW 8 ABC` in your first input file (as in your question) and let's call it as `file1.csv`. Once you're done execute `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) && a[$1]==$2' FS=, file2.csv FS=" " file1.csv` as it is and tell me if you've got any result at your end or not.

Comment: @batMan: No result. How puzzling.

Comment: @DanielEsporma: Now do `cat file1.csv` and `cat file2.csv` one by one and paste some result in your original question. I doubt the delimiter in your case. Also, are you getting the result via `grep` ? Are the words in same case (uppercase / lowercase) in both files ? And tell me the output for this grep command `grep -iwf <(tr "," " " <file2) file1`   -i is for ignoring case.

Comment: `($1 in a) && a[$1]==$2` can be reduced to `a[$1]==$2`

Comment: @batMan: `cat file1.csv` gives `YELLOW 8 ABC` and `cat file2.csv` gives `BROWN,2
RED,5
YELLOW,8`

Comment: `BROWN,2 RED,5 YELLOW,8` are these separated by newline ?

Comment: @batMan Yes, the output has them separated by newline. I couldn't figure out how to include that here in the comments section (again, sorry for being ridiculously new)

Comment: @DanielEsporma: no no .. I was just asking .. even I'm not sure if we could put newline in comments. let me see.

Comment: @batMan: Oh ok, also `grep -iwf <(tr "," " " <file2.csv) file1.csv` did not output anything

Comment: @DanielEsporma: That's strange. Only way I can help you is , if you can paste result of cat on https://pastebin.com/ and share with me the link. Also which OS are you on and what's the version of `awk` you're using. command is `awk --version`

Comment: @batMan: `awk version 20070501` I unfortunately can't use pastebin at work, but I can try following up at home. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @DanielEsporma Try this and let me know if it doesn't work `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}  ($1 in a) && a[$1]==$2{print}' FS="," file2.csv FS=" " file1.csv`

Comment: @batMan: Still nothing :/

Comment: @DanielEsporma I had to change `BROWN,2` to `BROWN,1` in `file2.csv` or there weren't any matches.

Comment: If you created the CSV files on Windows, make sure you convert the newlines. Use `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to do the matching.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; }
     NR == FNR { a[$1,$2]++; next; }
     FNR == 1 { FS=" "; }
     ($1,$2) in a' file2.csv file1.csv
```

The second line creates an array whose keys are the values in `file2.csv`. The third line changes the field separator to space when we're processing `file1.csv`, and the last line matches any line where the first two fields are a key in the array.

Comment: You can use `FNR==1 {FS=" "}` so you don't need to change the FS for every line of the 2nd file

Comment: To follow up on batMan's comment, `($1 FS $2) in a`

Comment: Sorry for the ridiculously nooby question, but how do I enter a 4 line command into the terminal? Should I make it a script and run it from there?

Comment: Just type the 4 lines. The shell knows it's not done because of the unclosed quotation.

Comment: But if you need to do it repeatedly, put it in a script.

Comment: You can also put the `awk` code in a file, and use `awk -f filename file2.csv file1.csv`

Comment: @Barmar: If I put the awk code in a file, should I leave the single quotes?

Comment: No, those are for the shell.

Comment: Weird, I'm not getting any output :/

Comment: I edited the script, using `,` between `$1` and `$2` in the array key. I tested it and it works.

Comment: instead of `FNR == 1 { FS=" "; }` you can just `file2.csv FS=" " file1.csv`, just before reading file1

Comment: @Barmar: I wasn't able to get the updated script to work either

Comment: @3161993 I know, I learned that from batMan's answer after I had already posted mine.